# BreakIterator behaving differently in Android API 29 and API 30

Tags: java, android, icu, breakiterator

I have made the below function to break String into Hindi Chars. But It behaves differently android API 29 and API 30. In Android 29 Hindi word चक्की is broken into च क् की But in Android 30 it is correctly broken into च क्की.

```
public List<String> breakIntoHindiChar(String textAnswer) {
    List<String> ansCharList = new ArrayList<String>();
    Locale hindi = new Locale("hi", "IN");
    BreakIterator breaker = BreakIterator.getCharacterInstance(hindi);
    breaker.setText(textAnswer);
    int start = breaker.first();
    for (int end = breaker.next();
         end != BreakIterator.DONE;
         start = end, end = breaker.next()) {

        ansCharList.add(textAnswer.substring(start, end));

    }
    return ansCharList;

}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Android implementation of BreakIterator was not able to interpret Bharatiya scripts (abiguda type) accurately. See this bug - https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=230832

Looks like it has been fixed for API 30 and has not been backported for previous versions.

Comment: So what is the solution?

Comment: @StephenC There is no viable solution other than to wait for Android 11 to become widely available on mobile devices. Recently I built a word search game in dictionary app for https://xn--l1b6a9di5a0j.xn--h2brj9c/ and due to BreakIterator bug, I had disabled game on devices having this bug.

Comment: Apart from the possible solutions I suggested ... of course :-)

Answer (score 1):

> How can I solve this problem?

As you noted in your question, the behavior in Android 29 is incorrect, and the behavior in Android 30 is correct.

So it depends on *what you think the problem is*:

- If you think that it is that they fixed the behavior in Android 30 at that has "broken" your app on later versions, then a solution would be for you to *copy* the Android 29 `BreakIterator` into your app (with a different name) and use it.
- If you think that it is that they didn't fix the behavior in Android 29 (and earlier) and you want your app to behave correctly on older Android, then a solution would be for you to *copy* the Android 30 `BreakIterator` into your app (with a different name) and use it.

Note that what you would be doing is to implement either forwards or backwards compatible behavior for `BreakIterator`, albeit not in the standard class.

<sup>(There may be a more elegant solution, but I don't have my own local copy of the Android master repo to dig through the history.)</sup>

Note: If you can't replace all of your app's use of `BreakIterator` with an alternative version of the class, then (AFAIK) there won't be a way to make the behavior consistent.  You cannot patch the Android platform.  And note that while you could use `android.icu.text.BreakIterator` instead of `android.text.BreakIterator` in your own code, that wouldn't fix the problem for other code that your app depends on.

---

But if you think **the problem** is that `BreakIterator` behaves differently in Android 29 vs 30 ... there is no solution to that.  It is a fact.  Yes ... it does behave differently ... and even Google can't make it not behave differently in Android 30 ... now.

Comment: It is not as simple as copying just one class named BreakIterator. BreakIterator is supported by lots classes. Bundling ICU implementation of BreakIterator with the app would be a better solution though it will increase app size significantly hence not recommended.

Comment: It >will< fix the example in the OP's question.  And if it doesn't fix the problem in the OP's app, then there probably isn't any solution.  (Bundling ICU wouldn't solve it either.)